# How to call jQuery event from another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have a question regarding the issue as title.
There is Page 1 with jQuery controlling to show the div, section 1 and section 2, as below.

```js
$('.section2,.click1').fadeOut(0);
$('.click2').on('click', function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(0);
  $('.section1').fadeOut();
  $('.section2, .click1').fadeIn();
});
$('.click1').on('click', function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(0);
  $('.section2').fadeOut();
  $('.section1, .click2').fadeIn();
});
```

```css
a {
  display:block;
}
.section-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width:400px;
  height: 140px;
}
.section-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.section1 {
  background: red;
}
.section2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="click2">Click to section2.</a>
<a class="click1">Click to section1.</a>
<div class="section-wrapper">
  <div class="section-box section1">
    I am section 1, default section.
  </div>
  <div class="section-box section2" id="Section2">
    I am section 2.
  </div>
</div>
```

However, when I am at Page 2, there's a button need to link me to the section 2.

```
<a href="page1.html#Section2">Go to Page 1 Section 2</a>
```

How can I call the jquery function to show the section 2 and hide the section 1?

Comment: you can add condition on page load with hashtag in url. To check which section should visible

Answer (score 0):

You could check for hash tag in page url and show/hide the element.

Edited

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(window.location.hash) {
   var hashVal = window.location.hash.substring(1);
   if(hashVal == "Section2"){
     var divId = "#"+hashVal; //id of the section 2 element

     $('.section1').fadeOut();
     $('.section2, .click1').fadeIn();

     var pos = $(divId).offset().top; //top position relative to the document
     $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: pos}); 

   }    
  } else {
  // No hash value
  }
});
```

Comment: oh this is work! however, if my link already has "page.html#scrolldown", may i know how can i add the Section2 in the href link? Because basically I need to scroll down and view the section 2

Comment: I think you cannot use multiple hashtags in an URL

Comment: it's there any jquery i can put under the if to call the page just scroll down?

Comment: Yes, code has been updated. Please check if it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is more generic

```js
$(function() {
  $('.click').on('click', function() {
    let sectionNumber = $(this).data("section");
    $(".click").show();
    $(this).fadeOut(0);
    $('.section-box').not(".section"+sectionNumber).fadeOut();
    $('.section'+sectionNumber).fadeIn()
  });


  let hash = "#section2" // change to location.hash when happy
  let section = hash ? hash.substring(1).replace("scrolldown&","") : "section1";

  if (hash) { 
    let sectionNumber = hash.replace(/\D+/,"");
    $("[data-section="+sectionNumber+"]").click()
  }  
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}

.section-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 140px;
}

.section-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.section1 {
  background: red;
}

.section2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="click" data-section="2">Click to section 2.</a>
<a class="click" data-section="1">Click to section 1.</a>
<div class="section-wrapper">
  <div class="section-box section1">
    I am section 1, default section.
  </div>
  <div class="section-box section2" id="Section2">
    I am section 2.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this seems workable, but it's deep for me, i don't know how to use. ><;;;